# How can I access the last result in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

In python REPL I can do things like:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(_)
10
```

In clojure REPL I can do this:

```
user=> "Hello!"
"Hello!"

user=> *1
"Hello!"
```

Is there is something like this in Scala REPL?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, you can use dot notation to refer to the last result:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> .sum
res1: Int = 10
```

Comment: This doesn't work for something like `scala> 4 + 5` and then `scala> . * 3`.  Please provide more detail as my google search for 'scala .' is not helping.

Comment: I should add it does work for something like a shell command result: `scala> :sh ls -l` and then `scala> .lines foreach println`

Answer (score 9):

You can refer to the previous output as `resN` for some `N`.  You've probably noticed that in the Scala REPL, results are printed in the form `resN: Type = value`:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> List(1,2,3,4)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> "Hello!"
res1: java.lang.String = Hello!
```

Well, that `resN` is a real variable name.  In this example, you can refer to the list as `res0` and the string as `res1` for (at least as far as I know) as long as the REPL is open:

```
scala> (res0.toString + res1) toLowerCase
res2: java.lang.String = list(1, 2, 3, 4)hello!
```

Answer (score -1):

I normally just hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> key to bring back the last line of code and carry on typing. This has the advantage of keeping the whole expression together for easy cutting-and-pasting or editing later.