# last result in Ruby REPL

Tags: ruby, scope, irb, read-eval-print-loop

In the Scala REPL if you evaluate something its value is stored in res{N}, as is discussed here: [How can I access the last result in Scala REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972339/how-can-i-access-the-last-result-in-scala-repl). Is there a similar feature for the ruby REPL, or do the results get lost if you don't capture their value in a variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the underscore `_` in irb to refer to the last returned result:

```
1 + 5
# => 6

_ + 10
# => 16
```

Comment: Is there some way to get the last returned result when executing a ruby script like this (not in irb)?

Comment: No, and there's not really a reason to. You can an assign any expression to a local variable (even `_` if you want to, though you probably shouldn't), but it's not implicitly assigned by the vm.